# How to include weatherwidget.io in dynamically built html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add weatherwidget.io's widget to my website, but need to dynamically use a string based on the users current location. For example, I'll include a hard string, but know that I pull the string based on the location.

```html
this.weatherwidget = '
<div><a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/38d91n77d04/washington/?unit=us" data-label_1="Washington Monument" data-label_2="National Mall" data-font="Arimo" data-theme="sky">Washington Monument National Mall</a>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, "script", "weatherwidget-io-js");
  </script>';
```

I did read that HTML 5 does NOT allow embedded script and I tried the only other solution I could find which was to embed this in an img onload event like so:

```html
<img src='empty.gif' onload='"https://forecast7.com/en/38d91n77d04/washington/?unit=us" data-label_1="Washington Monument" data-label_2="National Mall" data-font="Arimo" data-theme="sky" >Washington Monument National Mall</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","weatherwidget-io-js");</script>';
```

but this also doesn't seem to work. How does one dynamically build hmtl which includes a script??

Comment: The issue there that it has id 'https://forecast7.com/en/38d91n77d04/washington/?unit=us' after `en` part. So even if you will be able to embed that, they do not provide this id. I searched several widgets, none of them supports the dynamic search. So maybe create your own elements with weather api, f.e. https://openweathermap.org/api? But does it worth it?

Comment: I guess it would be possible to build my own, but I would prefer to just use one of the embedded ones, if I can figure out how to call it dynamically. The id you reference above is dependent on the area. What I was doing was creating a different link for each place I included on my map. Then, when a user clicked a pin, the weather for that particular area would be loaded by first doing an ajax call back to the server for the embedded text, ie, everything between the <div> tags, though I just noticed the final </div> is missing from the snippet.

Comment: Dunno if you ever figured this out but I was looking today to do the same thing and thing I've done it.

Comment: In my case the weather widget was loading once on my page but once I tried to load it again via ajax it wasn't loading.

Comment: In my case, there was a cost to use the widget, so I created an html table which was populated via a php call to darksky for the weather.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610395/issue-unbinding-domsubtreemodified-within-itself-and-settimeout